# L'Hopital's Rule not working on $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{-3x+2}{x+\sin x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I got this equation here:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{-3x+2}{x+\sin x}}$

Which is $\frac{-3\cdot\infty+2}{\infty+sin(\infty)}$ which is $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$ so I get to use lhoptial rule right?

I do that and get this:
$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\left(-3\right)}{1+\cos x}}$

But that doesn't seem to lead anywhere since cosine is always oscillating.

The graph shows that too: [image]
I know that you can probably just use $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ goes to 1 at 0 for the first step, but why can't you use lhopitals like I did?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the statement of l'Hôpital's rule, the original limit equals the new limit *if the new limit exists* (that requirement is just a part of the theorem). In this case, the new limit does not exist, so l'Hôpital's rule gives no information. But in particular it doesn't give false information—nowhere does l'Hôpital's rule say that the original limit shouldn't exist if the new limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

For L'Hôpital's rule to work on $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, you need $g'(x)\neq0$ for all $x$ in the whole interval you are considering. In your case, $g'(x)=1+\cos x=0$ for any $x=(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ for arbitrarily large integer $k$, so the criterion fails here.

Comment: Is this really the issue? If we change the original denominator from $x+\sin x$ to $2x+\sin x$, then the derivative of the new denominator is never $0$, yet the same "paradox" persists.

Comment: Moreover, there is another issue, indeed there should exist the limit $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f’(x)}{g’(x)}\;.$

Comment: The l'Hospital rule requires among other things the existence of the limit $\lim {f'\over g'}. $ If the latter does not hold the limit $\lim {f\over g}$ may still exist. Another example can be provided by $\lim_{x\to \infty}{x\over 2x+\sin(e^x)}.$ Thus we should not abuse the rule.

Comment: I don't understand how $x=\pi\left(k+1/2\right)$ for large integer $k$ has to do with anything. If the original problem had $3x+\sin{x}$ in the denominator, then the derivative of the bottom would never be $0$ for any $x$.

Comment: The limit is equivalent to $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow0^+}\frac{-3+2t}{1+t\sin\frac{1}{t}}$. One of the conditions for L'Hôpital's rule to work is that you have an interval containing $t$ such that $\frac{f'}{g'}\neq0$ on the interval, but the function is always zero at $\frac{1}{k}$. For arbitrarily large $k$, these zero points are always in the interval containing $0$.@Accelerator